# Infragistics zoombar size change default value

Tags: c#, wpf-controls, infragistics, wpf-4.0

The Infragistics zoombar default position is as shown below.
[image]

but i need it like :[image]
 please let me know how can i customize it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you seen this [Data Chart Integration](http://www.infragistics.com/products/wpf/sample/zoombar/data-chart-integration) ([identical Silverlight live version](http://www.infragistics.com/products/silverlight/sample/zoombar/#/data-chart-integration)) sample? It kind of does what you want.

As described in the [documentation](http://help.infragistics.com/doc/WPF/2013.2/CLR4.0/?page=xamZoombar_Getting_Started_with_xamZoombar.html) the Zoombar's thumb location and size are determined by the range, so looking at your image I think you want range like { 0.9 - 1 }:

```
<ig:XamZoombar>
    <ig:XamZoombar.Range>
        <ig:Range Minimum="0.9" Maximum="1"></ig:Range>
    </ig:XamZoombar.Range>
</ig:XamZoombar>
```

Adjust the minimum value to match what you want to achieve and check out the documentation/sample for snippets to set it in code.

**EDIT:** In the case where you have the Zoombar in sync with a chart via range binding you would have something like this instead:

```
<ig:XamZoombar Name="xamZoomBar" Range="{Binding ElementName=xamChart, Path=HorizontalZoombar.Range, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Or like seen in the sample in code behind after components have been initialized:

```
Binding binding = new Binding
{
    Source = this.xamChart,
    Path = new PropertyPath("HorizontalZoombar.Range"),
    Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay
};
this.xamZoomBar.SetBinding(Infragistics.Controls.XamZoombar.RangeProperty, binding);
```

after which you can set the range and still keep the binding(sync) active:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    // Binding in code goes here if needed
    this.xamZoomBar.Range = new Infragistics.Controls.Range { Minimum = 0.9, Maximum = 1 };
}
```

Again, this is all available in the sample linked above. There's also an alternative way to sync the chart and zoombar via events shown there.

Comment: i am synchronizing this zoombar with my "xmDataChart"(chart which i want to zoom in). using
     Range="{Binding ElementName=xmDataChart, Path=HorizontalZoombar.Range, Mode=TwoWay}"
the moment i use this solution, i loos the synchronization with the "xmdataChart". Let me know how can i use the combination of both.

Comment: I hope you've seen the sample I linked because it does exactly that - sync the XamZoombar with the XamDataChart and set initial range in code behind. Either way, I've updated the answer above to include that scenario for future reference.